# FuelUX - Open datepicker calendar upward

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fuelux

What is the best way to open the datepicker calendar upwards? The default is to open downwards. I have changed the margin to a negative value on datepicker-calendar-wrapper class and it works fine, but wondering if theres any other way to do this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa0oxgn3/8/)

```
.datepicker-calendar-open-up {
    margin: -356px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `dropup` class to `datepicker` wrapper.

```
<div class="datapicker dropup">
    ...
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvrfat1y/1/

The datepicker is is built around bootstrap dropdowns control which includes a dropup variation.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup